# How to keep session alive without modifying the client in JAVA

Tags: java, session

I have the server which responds after 1 hour and my client has session timeout of 10 minutes.

So when client requests server, server starts processing but after 10 minutes the session expires at client side.

So can anyone tell me how can i keep the session alive for 1 hour to send the appropriate response to client.

I dont want to change my client at all. I used java servlet to create server.

Comment: post any code or work you have done

Comment: Sessions have short timeouts because they're intended to serve many clients at the same time, so it won't run out of resources. Said that, the usual mechanism for this kind of problem is to implement some kind of polling (periodically try to get the results). In this case you will need one service to submit the request and another one to ask for the response, when it's ready (or just show a message that "there's no response for this request yet)

Comment: any more info about your application and server? Is it web application? What do you mean "server" and "client"?

Comment: If you need to implement this like you described, trick is to write 1-byte char(empty ' ' is fine) every 5min to a responsestream. But if client is waiting for a strict binary and not leading whitespace tolerable html reply you have a problem.

Comment: my server is normal java program running on Apache tomcat.
And client is also java program.
I am doing this for testing purpose once this is successful i will have to implement it in other product.

Comment: @Whome can you give me sample code for your solution.

Comment: Try mockup servlet first to simulate session-keepalive if idea worked. long remaining=60*60*1000; while(remaining>0) { Thread.sleep(3*60*1000); remaining-=3*60*1000; out.getWriter().write(' '); out.getWriter().flush(); } out.getWriter().write("<xml>done</xml>"); out.getWriter().flush();